# Cannot Convert JSON to Python List

Tags: python, json

I am a beginner at Python.  I imported the Twitter test feed below, changed it to a JSON string, but am unable to convert it to a Python list.  I tried 2 versions of code to do this, one of which I found on this site.  They are listed below along with their output as well as a short segment of my input string.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this as it is unclear to me what I am doing wrong.

1)Subset of input string called `tweet_text_list`:

`'[\'#mindset on #millionaire #goals #stocks #world #class\\xa0 #financial #boss #finesse #moves\\xa0 #study the #money #game… , "#Stocks #Investing #Stockmarket #nanoStockAnalysis Infosys\' (INFY) CEO Vishal Sikka on Q4 2017 Results - Earnin... ", \'RT @ElixiumNeptune: #Trading with #Bitcoin\#Forex #Stocks $ES $CL $GC $GOOG $AAPL $TSLA $SPY $QQQ…\']'`

2)Code from this site:

```
import json

tweets_data = []

class JSONObject:
    def __init__( self, dict ):
        vars(self).update( dict )

tweets_data = json.loads(tweet_text_list, object_hook= JSONObject)
```

Output: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

3)Another code attempt:

```
tweets_data = []

for line in tweet_list:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line) 
        tweets_data.append(tweet) 
    except:
        continue
print(tweets_data )
```

Output: `[]`

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: "Changed it to a JSON string"... How did you do that? Because you don't have a JSON string here

Comment: I used tweet_text_list=str([tweet.text for tweet in tweet_list])

Answer (score 1):

> `'[\'#mindset on #millionaire #goals #stocks #world #class\\xa0 #financial #boss #finesse #moves\\xa0 #study the #money #game… , "#Stocks #Investing #Stockmarket #nanoStockAnalysis Infosys\' (INFY) CEO Vishal Sikka on Q4 2017 Results - Earnin... ", \'RT @ElixiumNeptune: #Trading with #Bitcoin\#Forex #Stocks $ES $CL $GC $GOOG $AAPL $TSLA $SPY $QQQ…\']'`

That isn't a JSON encoded string. JSON only uses quotes, not apostrophes, to delimit strings. (You can find the JSON specification over [here](http://www.json.org/).)

The correct way to convert a Python value into JSON encoded string is via [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps), as in:

```
tweet_text_list = json.dumps([tweet.text for tweet in tweet_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

> I used tweet_text_list=str([tweet.text for tweet in tweet_list])

That is a Python string. If you want a JSON string, give this a try.

```
tweets_json = json.dumps([tweet.text for tweet in tweet_list])
```